# How can I see all my code without scrolling in Android Studio? (I mean all code in one page without scrolling)

Tags: android, android-studio

You know scrolling in code is very annoying
is there any solution to get rid of it?
I mean I want to preview my code ALL in one page without any scrolling.

[image]

Comment: You can go to settings and set font to the least one.

Comment: so in this case(small font size) my eye don't see.

Comment: :D but i heard vs code has something like this .but i don't know  about  this feature in android studio that i work with it

Comment: Attach image from what you want please

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abNLm.jpg

Comment: You can see the codes?!

Comment: ok i admit that best way is your solution (small font size)

Comment: please make your comment as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to settings and set font to the least one.

Answer (score 0):

go to android studio settings -> plugins; and search for `codeGlance` . install plugin and restart your ide. and voila.